# /proc directory script

Tags: ruby, linux, popen, procfs

I'm looking for a ruby script that accesses the `/proc` directory and saves the process ID and command line (`cmdline`) information in a file.

Comment: FYI, there is a kernel bug that prevents File.open from working properly with /proc files. We encountered this in Facter and only fixed it by shelling out to `cat` instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you may want to call `ps` instead of going to `/proc`.

```
cmd=`ps -eo pid,cmd`
o = File.open("output","w")
o.write(cmd)
o.close
```

Comment: Nice one, though I'd advocate showing the block form of File.open so that the file handle is closed for you: `File.open('output','w'){ |f| f << \`ps -eo pid,cmd\` }`

Answer (score 0):

you can also run below one liner bash script and redirect its output anywhere, as well as choose required argument option for head command.

```
ls -alR /proc/$(ls /proc/ |grep -i '[0-9]'|sort -n|head ) > /proc_open_files
```